# Detect internet connection on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Ok so this is the code I'm using to detect internet connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if(ni.isConnected())
                        //do stuff if there is internet connection
                    else
                       //do stuff if there is no internet connection
```

However even though my pc is not connected to the internet the emulator thinks he is so how do I get around this? Also the wireless device is turned off.

Comment: I think you have turn on Aeroplane mode of emulator.it's disable all connection.

Comment: I did but then in the log it says device disconnected and I cant get any error log and the app crashes in airplane mode

Comment: This command will disable network on emulator: adb shell svc data disable

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public boolean isConnectionAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: same result it returns true, I've turn Airplane mode on to make it work, apparently the emulator does not know if the pc doesn't have internet

Comment: any way to to this without airplane mode because it disconnects from eclipse and I get no more logs?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu I never needed to switch on Airplane mode when I used this code!

Comment: @Hardy any idea about this issue?

Comment: it never goes to the part of the code where isConnectionAvailable returns false unless in airplane mode

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I hope it useful to you..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean determineConnectivity(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return info != null && info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    }
```